# GKE Ingress shows unhealthy backend services

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a GKE cluster with 4 nodes in an instance group.
I deployed Ingress and several pods (1 replica only of each pod so they are only on 1 node).
I notice on the Google Console (Ingress details page) that all backend services remain Unhealhy although the healthchecks on the running pods are OK and my application is running.
To my understanding it says it is unhealthy because out of the 4 nodes, only 1 node is running an instance of a given pod (on the Back-end service details it says "1 of 4 instances healthy").
Am I correct and should I worry and try to fix this? It's bit strange to accept an Unhealthy status when the application is running...

Edit:
After further investigation, down to 2 nodes, and activating the healthcheck logs, I can see that the backend service status seems to be the status of the last executed healthcheck. So if it checks last the node that hosts the pod, it is healthy, else it is unhealthy.

GKE version: 1.16.13-gke.1

My ingress definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: mcrt-dc729887-5c67-4388-9327-e4f76baf9eaf
    ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: '{"k8s-be-30301--503461913abc33d7":"UNHEALTHY","k8s-be-31206--503461913abc33d7":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-31253--503461913abc33d7":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-31267--503461913abc33d7":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-31432--503461913abc33d7":"UNHEALTHY","k8s-be-32238--503461913abc33d7":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-32577--503461913abc33d7":"UNHEALTHY","k8s-be-32601--503461913abc33d7":"UNHEALTHY"}'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule: k8s2-fs-sfdowd2x-city-foobar-cloud-8cfrc00p
    ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy: k8s2-ts-sfdowd2x-city-foobar-cloud-8cfrc00p
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert: mcrt-dc729887-5c67-4388-9327-e4f76baf9eaf
    ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s2-um-sfdowd2x-city-foobar-cloud-8cfrc00p
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: city
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: foobar-cloud
  creationTimestamp: "2020-08-06T08:25:18Z"
  finalizers:
  - networking.gke.io/ingress-finalizer-V2
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: foobar-cloud
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: foobar-cloud
    helm.sh/chart: foobar-cloud-0.4.58
  name: foobar-cloud
  namespace: city
  resourceVersion: "37878"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/city/ingresses/foobar-cloud
  uid: 751f78cf-2344-46e3-b87e-04d6d903acd5
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: foobar-cloud-server
          servicePort: 9999
        path: /foobar/server
      - backend:
          serviceName: foobar-cloud-server
          servicePort: 9999
        path: /foobar/server/*
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Comment: Could you share your `Ingress` definition ?

Comment: I've edited my question with the `Ingress` definition and further investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the cause of this.
My services were not mentionning any value for `externalTrafficPolicy` so the default value of `Cluster` applied.
However, I have a NetworkPolicy  defined which goal was to prevent traffic from other namespaces,as described [here](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/04-deny-traffic-from-other-namespaces.md).
I added the IPs of the load balancers probes as stated in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy#working_with_https_load_balancer_health_checks) but was missing the *allow connections from other node IPs in the cluster.*

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar issue. I don't need to share my setup as it's almost identical to the OP's.  I'm using the GKE Ingress Controller also like the OP.  I had manually added externalTrafficPolicy: Local to the service called by the Ingress Controller backend service and when I changed the externalTrafficPolicy from 'Local' to 'Cluster' (as per dany L above) the Ingress backend service immediately reported healthy.

I removed the 'externalTrafficPolicy:' lines from the called Service and am now set up with a GKE Ingress Controller using conatainer native load balancing with all backend services reporting healthy.

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem: GCP network endpoint saying the backend was unhealthy.

The problem in my case was that my application would not return 200 in `/`, because it requires authentication.

Make sure you configure `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe` to do an `httpGet` to a path that returns 200 OK. In my case:

```yaml
livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
        path: /ping
        port: 4180
readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
        path: /ping
        port: 4180
```

---

More details:

When the `Ingress` is created, the controller that tells GCP how to configure the Cloud Loadbalancer copies from the `Deployment` spec the info about the probes, and that is what it is used to determine the health of the Google Cloud backend endpoint.

I discovered this because when I deployed my application I had no probes configured. Then I edited the deployment and added both probes but it didn't work. I could see this in the logs of my app:

```
[2021/11/22 18:38:43] [oauthproxy.go:862] No valid authentication in request. Initiating login.
130.211.1.166:32768 - e8d8b7f9-8cc9-419a-aeb8-898260169a2c - - [2021/11/22 18:38:43] 10.56.2.24 GET - "/" HTTP/1.1 "GoogleHC/1.0" 403 8092 0.000
10.56.2.1:45770 - e7a9d52a-ecbe-4e1c-af69-65ddf432d92c - - [2021/11/22 18:38:50] 10.56.2.24:4180 GET - "/ping" HTTP/1.1 "kube-probe/1.20+" 200 2 0.000
```

As you can see, there is a request to `/` from an agent with code "GoogleHC/1.0". This is what GCP uses to determine if the backend is healthy.

Then there is another request to `/ping` from an agent with code `kube-probe/1.20+`, that is the `readinessProbe` in Kubernetes.

Then I deleted the `Ingress` and created it again, and this time it worked:

```
130.211.1.180:39854 - d069dd2c-6733-4029-8c9b-fa03917ca2a7 - - [2021/11/22 18:57:32] 10.56.2.27 GET - "/ping" HTTP/1.1 "GoogleHC/1.0" 200 2 0.000
10.56.2.1:35598 - 85eeaf1c-a6e6-4cc8-a6ed-931f504f9493 - - [2021/11/22 18:57:36] 10.56.2.27:4180 GET - "/ping" HTTP/1.1 "kube-probe/1.20+" 200 2 0.000
```

Both agents using the right path for the readiness probe.

Comment: Thank you! Just need to report the `readynessProbe` typo. It is a 'I' rather than a 'Y': `readinessProbe`.

Comment: thank you @MartinTovmassian, I have edited that in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Cloud is necessary have a endpoint that return code 200.
For C# .Net Core you can see how to do in [Health Check](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
After you create the endpoint, you need to configure two things:

1. Create a BackendConfig to define the url (request path)

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: http-hc-config
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 60
    port: 80
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /health
```

2. Define in annotations in service "cloud.google.com/backend-config"

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
  annotations: 
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "http-hc-config"}'
spec:
  selector:
    type: app
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80  
  type: NodePort
```

For me this work.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue as @jfc.

I specified `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe` in my pod with custom healthcheck path.

It was sufficient to fix `kube-probe` healthchecks but not enough to fix `GoogleHC` healthchecks. I had to manually configure the healthchek in the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/healthChecks).

Answer (score -1):

Please check your yaml file for your service. If it shows [externalTrafficPolicy: local](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip), then it is expected behavior.

Local means traffic will always go to a pod on the same node, while everything else is dropped. So if your deployment has only 1 replica it is serving, you will only have one healthy instance.

You can easily test that theory, scale up to 2 replicas and observe behavior. I forsee 1 healthy instance if 2nd replica lands on the same node as first replica and 2/4 healthy if 2nd replica lands on a different node. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've seen posts refering to this setting, but to my knowledge it refers to the ingress-nginx controller, which is not the one used in GKE (I rely on the default GKE controller and I do not create a LoadBalancer myself).