# How to solve "Ingress Error: Some backend services are in UNHEALTHY state"?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am working on deploying a certain pod to GKE but I am having an unhealthy state for my backend services.

The deployment went through via `helm install process` but the ingress reports a certain warning error that says `Some backend services are in UNHEALTHY state`. I have tried to access the logs but do not know exactly what to look out for. Also, I already have liveness and readiness probes running.

What could I do to make the ingress come back to a healthy state? Thanks

[Picture of warning error on GKE UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNcFg.png)

Comment: Please put detailed error as "text" not image or link.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42971328/2777988

Comment: Please provide which GKE version are you using. How did you deployed `Nginx`, can you share your `helm` command? Could you share your `Ingress` yaml, **without** private information like your IP or private `hosts`? Please check if all pods are running correctly `$ kubectl get po -n <yourAppNamespace>` and share in your question. All pods are in `Ready` and in `Running` status? There is information that `Some backend`, not `All backend` which indicates that you have issue with some pods (maybe insufficient CPU, Memory).

Answer (score 3):

Without more details it is hard to determine the exact cause.

As first point I want to mention, that your error message is `Some backend services are in UNHEALTHY state`, **not** `All backend services are in UNHEALTHY state`. It indicates that only **a few of your backends** are affected.

There might be tons of reasons, if you are using `GCP Ingress` or `Nginx Ingress`, your configuration of `externalTrafficPolicy`, if you are using `preemptive nodes`, your `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe`, `health checks`, etc.

In your scenario, only a few backends are affected, the only thing with current information I can suggest you some debug options.

- Using `$ kubectl get po -n <namespace>` check if all your pods are working correctly, that all containers within pods are `Ready` and pod status is `Running`. Eventually check logs of suspicious pod `$ kubectl logs <podname> -c <containerName>`. In general you should check all pods the load balancer is pointing to,
- Confirm if `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe` are configured properly and response is `200`,
- Describe your ingress `$ kubectl describe ingress <yourIngressName>` and check `backends`,
- Check if you've configured your `health checks` properly according to [GKE Ingress for HTTP(S) Load Balancing - Health Checks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#health_checks) guide.

If you still won't be able to solve this issue with above debug options, please provide more details about your env with logs (without private information).

**Useful links**:

- [kubernetes unhealthy ingress backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294305/)
- [GKE Ingress shows unhealthy backend services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63268552/gke-ingress-shows-unhealthy-backend-services)

Answer (score 0):

In GKE you can define `BackendConfig`. To define custom health checks. you can configure this using the below link to make the ingress backend to be in a HEALTHY state.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#direct_health

Answer (score -2):

If you have kubectl access to your pods, you can run `kubectl get pod`, and then `kubctl logs -f <pod-name>`.
Review the logs and find the error(s).

Comment: Thanks for the response. What pod exactly? I do not see any ingress pod in my list of pods

Comment: Backend services are the services behind the ingress; meaning the actual pods that should receive and process the request, not an ingress pod. Please check the logs of the application pods, starting with the pod that should handle incoming requests.